# How to solve $2\ln(x)<9x^{1/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this?

$$2\ln(x)<9x^{1/3}$$

I tried everything but it does not work.

I know that is true for $x>0$ but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the derivative with respect to $x$ of the function $9 x^{1/3} - 2 \ln x$ which is $\frac{3}{x^{2/3}} - \frac{2}{x}$. For $x > 0$, it is greater than 0 iff $x > 8/27$. But, for $0 < x < 1, \ln x < 0$ while $x^{1/3} > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply both sides with $\dfrac13$ , use the fact that $a\ln b=\ln b^a$ , then let $t=\sqrt[3]x$ , and plot $\dfrac{\ln t}t$ .

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by derivative.

Assume $$f(x) = 2\mathbb{ln}(x) - 9x^{1/3}$$
Then $$f'(x) = \frac{2 - 3x^{1/3}}{x} $$
when $x>0$, we just need to focus on the numerator. And we can simply find the extreme point $ x = (\frac{2}{3})^3$. And we also get that $f(x)$ is increasing when $x<(\frac{2}{3})^3$ , and $f(x)$ is decreasing when $x\geq(\frac{2}{3})^3$. Therefore, $x = (\frac{2}{3})^3$ is the maximum point. However $$f((\frac{2}{3})^3) = 2\mathbb{ln}((\frac{2}{3})^3) - 9(\frac{2}{3})^3)^{1/3} = 6\mathbb{ln}(\frac{2}{3}) - 6 < 6\mathbb{ln}(\mathbb{e}) - 6 = 0. $$ Then we can get that $f(x) < 0$ in $(0,\infty)$, so the proof is over.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<x<1$ we have $2\ln x<0<9x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. By the Mean Value Theo., for $x>1$ there exist $1<c<x$ such that $\ln x=\ln x - \ln1=\frac{1}{c}(x-1)<\frac{1}{c}x<x$. In particular, for $x>1$ we have $0<\ln x^\frac{1}{3}<x^\frac{1}{3}$ then
$\frac{1}{3}\ln x<x^\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow \ln x<3x^\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow 2\ln x<9x^\frac{1}{3}$.